# How to draw a polyline from an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, svg

I have an array with simple decimal values so what I want is that I am using SVG Polyline to create a LINECHART so I want to get some sort of PHP Plugin or a piece of code which can generate X & Y coordinates points for me from a simple array of decimal values.

I have tried alot with JS plugins and they were surely generating it better but then...!

NOTE : I can't use a JS Plugin like **d3.js** unfortunately I am using WKHTMLTOPDF Linux Binary which seems to be not working with JS Charts.

The arrays of values would be something like as :

```
[14,18,4,19,23,34,16,25,5,9,13,15,16]
```

Here is my Demo SVG Polyline :

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" style="width: 710px;height: 300px">
  
  <polyline
     fill="none"
     stroke="rgb(125, 207, 108)"
     stroke-width="4"
     points="
       00,120
       20,60
       40,80
       60,20
       80,80
       100,80
       120,60
       140,100
       160,90
       180,80
       200, 110
       220, 10
       240, 70
       260, 100
       280, 100
       300, 40
       320, 0
       340, 100
       360, 100
       380, 120
       400, 60
       420, 70
       440, 80
     "
   />
  
</svg>
```

**UPDATE :**
Thanks to @Paul LeBeau
I can now generate the linechart but can you please also just add the x axis values to each point on the chart beneath. That would be really great and also how can I stretch out the chart to cover this whole page as : 
[image]

The values beneath on the x axis should show up like this as Jul 2016 and etc  :

[image]

Here is array for the new data as :

```
$data=["Jul 2014"=>[16],
               "Aug 2014"=>[14],
               "Sep 2014"=>[18],
               "Oct 2014"=>[4],
               "Nov 2014"=>[19],
               "Dec 2014"=>[23],
               "Jan 2015"=>[34],
               "Feb 2015"=>[16],
               "Mar 2015"=>[25],
               "Apr 2015"=>[5],
               "May 2015"=>[9],
               "Jun 2015"=>[13],
               "Jul 2015"=>[15]];
```

And here is the PHP Code for the Lincharts as :

```
$values = [14,18,4,19,23,34,16,25,5,9,13,15,16];

$xOrigin = 90;   // Position of the start (left) of the X axis
$yOrigin = 100;  // Position of the start (bottom) of the Y axis
$xScale = 20;    // Scale for the X axis
$yScale = 2.5;   // Scale for the Y axis

// Get the max value in the $values array so we know how tall to make the Y axis
$yMax = max($values);

$linechart = "";

  $linechart .= '<g transform="translate('.$xOrigin.','.$yOrigin.')" fill="none" stroke="grey">';
    $linechart .= '<line id="xaxis" x1="0" y1="0" x2="'.$xScale*(count($values)-1).'" y2="0" />';
    $linechart .= '<line id="yaxis" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2=".'-$yScale*$yMax.'" />';

  $points = "";
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
          if ($i != 0)
            $points .= ", ";
          $points .=($i * $xScale) . "," . ($values[$i] * -$yScale);
        }


$polyline = "";
$polyline .= '<polyline
      stroke="rgb(125, 207, 108)"
      stroke-width="4"
      points="'.$points.'"/>
  </g>';


$page6 = <<<EOD
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" style="width: 710px;height: 300px;position: absolute;top: 3135px;left: 130px;">

      $linechart;

      $polyline

    </svg>
EOD;
```

Here is a link for the report which has the LINECHART where I am embedding it as : http://huntedhunter.com/venue_report/

Comment: I posted an answer but now I'm thinking I'm totally wrong... what are the values in the array supposed to be?

Comment: @ishegg : These are not pairs but simply just values of points which are to be rendered in it. It would be a simple line chart with ups and down according to the array.

Comment: Do you just need a very simple line chart?  I.e. just the line and axes. Or are you talking about a proper graph with auto-generated labels, tick marks,  etc?

Comment: @Paul LeBeau : Sure Just simple LINE CHART Would suffice for now but a proper graph can also be a good idea along but please don't forget the simple LINE CHART too.

Comment: I am willing to provide a bounty too on this soon.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau : Thank you for your amazing answer. Can you please read  my question back again. I have updated the question description.

Comment: To get the graph to scale properly, you will need to set the `<svg>` `viewBox` attribute appropriately.  To add labels to your chart, add `<text>` elements. It is very easy. There is plenty of information here on SO and elsewhere on the web on these two subjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some PHP code to draw a simple line graph with X and Y axes.

```
$values = [14,18,4,19,23,34,16,25,5,9,13,15,16];

$xOrigin = 90;   // Position of the start (left) of the X axis
$yOrigin = 100;  // Position of the start (bottom) of the Y axis
$xScale = 20;    // Scale for the X axis
$yScale = 2.5;   // Scale for the Y axis

// Get the max value in the $values array so we know how tall to make the Y axis
$yMax = max($values);

?><svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" style="width: 710px;height: 300px">

  <g transform="translate(<?=$xOrigin?>, <?=$yOrigin?>)" fill="none" stroke="grey">
    <line id="xaxis" x1="0" y1="0" x2="<?= $xScale*(count($values)-1) ?>" y2="0" />
    <line id="yaxis" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="<?= -$yScale*$yMax ?>" />

    <polyline
      stroke="rgb(125, 207, 108)"
      stroke-width="4"
      points="<?php

        // Loop through all the entries in the $values array
        // Echo "x,y" coordinates to the page to fill in the
        // points attribute of the <polyline> element.
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
          // If this is not the first x,y pair, then output a
          // comma to separate one x,y pair from the next
          if ($i != 0)
            echo ", ";
          // Output a single x,y pair.  Each x and y values are
          // multiplied by a scale factor. $yScale is negative because
          // in an SVG y coordinates increase down the page, but we want larger
          // Y to go up the page.
          echo ($i * $xScale) . "," . ($values[$i] * -$yScale);
        }

      ?>"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

An explanation of some of the SVG content:

```
<g transform="translate(<?=$xOrigin?>, <?=$yOrigin?>)" fill="none" stroke="grey">
```

This `<g>` element is an SVG group.  Groups are just ways to specify some properties that are inherited by all the groups children.  So we can set the `fill` to none, and the `stroke` colour to grey here, and we don't have to specifiy it for every child.

The `transform="translate()"` attribute causes the groups children to be shifted on the page tho the `$xOrigin`, `$yOrigin` position.  We are doing this to simplify the graph below.  We can create our graph and axes as if they were based at (0,0). Then the tranform shifts everything to the final location on the page.

```
<line id="xaxis" x1="0" y1="0" x2="<?= $xScale*(count($values)-1) ?>" y2="0" />
```

A line that forms the X axis. From `(0,0)` to `(<no. of values>, 0)`.

```
<line id="yaxis" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="<?= -$yScale*$yMax ?>" />
```

A line that forms the Y axis. From `(0,0)` to `(0, <maximum Y value>)`.

Comment: Can you explain the code please also? That would be great that what you did where and why and how it's working?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some extra comments and additional explanation. I hope this helps.